# select query using this format

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the data  in this format

```
      NAME1 AMOUNT1 Internal
      NAME1 AMOUNT1 External
      NAME2 AMOUNT2 Internal
      NAME2 AMOUNT2 External
```

but now i need to extract the data in the below format using *SQL-Server*

```
    NAME1 AMOUNT1 Internal
                  External
    NAME2 AMOUNT2 Internal
                  External
```

Please suggest.

Comment: do you actually need empty rows to be returned ? if yes, that's not possible with sql server

Comment: Hi, it is not empty rows, i want if same data is there in the next row then display as space

Comment: This is more of a presentation issue not typically and not easily solved in the sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve It by using [**ROW_NUMBER()**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) and [**CASE**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) in following:

**SAMPLE DATA:**

```
CREATE TABLE #t
(
   Name NVARCHAR(40),
   Amount NVARCHAR(40),
   Types NVARCHAR(40)
)
INSERT INTO #t VALUES
   ('NAME1', 'AMOUNT1', 'Internal'),
   ('NAME1', 'AMOUNT1', 'External'),
   ('NAME2', 'AMOUNT2', 'Internal'),
   ('NAME2', 'AMOUNT2', 'External')
```

---

**QUERY**

```
SELECT CASE WHEN rn > 1 THEN '' ELSE Name END AS Name,
       CASE WHEN rn > 1 THEN '' ELSE Amount END AS Amount,
       Types
FROM(
    SELECT Name, 
           Amount, 
           Types, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name, Amount ORDER BY Name) rn
    FROM #t
    ) x
```

---

**OUTPUT**

```
Name    Amount      Types
NAME1   AMOUNT1     Internal
                    External
NAME2   AMOUNT2     Internal
                    External
```

---

**DEMO**

You can test it: <kbd>[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f5641/1)</kbd>

Comment: when i include row_number in my sql query i am not able to retrive data at all. Please suggest